# How to code radio group for alerts with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I currently have a question within my HTML and a radio group with a simple yes or no. I would like to make it so that when the user answers yes, they get an alert that says good job. and when they answer no, the alert says try again and reloads the page.

Here is the html

```
    <div id="enterText"></div>

<img src="../img/Window1.jpg" width="500" height="300"><br>

<input type="radio" name="radio-group1" value="Yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="radio-group1" value="No">No<br><br>
<button id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
```

and here is the current javascript I have

```
if (document.title === "Level 3"){

    document.getElementById("enterText").innerHTML = "Look at the Picture below, Is it possible for the equation to be true?";

    document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", calcChoices, false);
}



function calcChoices(){
    var radioGroup = document.getElementsByName("radio-group1");
    for (var i = 0; i < radioGroup.length; i++) {
        if (radioGroup[i].checked){
            console.log("You clicked: "+ radioGroup[i].value);
        }
    }
    if(radioGroup[i].value="Yes"){
            alert("NICE!")
        }
        if(radioGroup[i].value="No"){
            alert("try again!")
        }
}
```

Comment: `location.reload()` to reload page http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will reload the page if they say no. Also, fixed minor bugs that said that the choice was `YES` every time.

```
if (document.title === "Level 3"){

    document.getElementById("enterText").innerHTML = "Look at the Picture below, Is it possible for the equation to be true?";

    document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", calcChoices, false);
}



 function calcChoices(){
      var radioGroup = document.getElementsByName("radio-group1");
      for (var i = 0; i < radioGroup.length; i++) {
           if (radioGroup[i].checked){
                console.log("You clicked: "+ radioGroup[i].value);
                if(radioGroup[i].value==="Yes"){
                     alert("NICE!");
                }
                if(radioGroup[i].value==="No"){
                     alert("try again!");
                     location.reload(); //Added this line
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code for your javascript:

```
document.getElementById("enterText").innerHTML = "Look at the Picture below, Is it possible for the equation to be true?";

document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", calcChoices, false);


function calcChoices(){
  var radioGroup = document.getElementsByName("radio-group1");
  for (var i = 0; i < radioGroup.length; i++) {
    if (radioGroup[i].checked) {
      if(radioGroup[i].value==="Yes"){
              alert("NICE!")
          }
        if(radioGroup[i].value==="No"){
            alert("try again!")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! It was just the simple difference between = and === correct?

Comment: Yes, that was pretty much all I changed :)

Comment: @AlexZai He also nested the if-statements and put them inside the for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code, I found a couple of things wrong. Your first if statement was not returning true so I added a title. Your last two if statements, I joined them together. Those two if statements where not in your for loop. and I fixed some common Boolean and semicolons errors. Here is the finalalised result:

```js
if (document.title === "Level 3") {

  document.getElementById("enterText").innerHTML = "Look at the Picture below, Is it possible for the equation to be true?";

  document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", calcChoices, false);
}



function calcChoices() {
  var radioGroup = document.getElementsByName("radio-group1");
  for (var i = 0; i < radioGroup.length; i++) {
    if (radioGroup[i].checked) {
      console.log("You clicked: " + radioGroup[i].value);
      if (radioGroup[i].value === "Yes") {
        alert("NICE!");
        break;
      } else {
        alert("Try Again!");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Level 3</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="enterText"></div>
  <img src="../img/Window1.jpg" width="500" height="300">
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-group1" value="Yes">Yes
  <input type="radio" name="radio-group1" value="No">No
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
</body>
```